# Floating action button over webview not working

Tags: java, android, button, webview

I have a map fragment using a webview and i want to add a button to submit a new location opening a new fragment to do this.

The button it's shown but it don't work.

I hope you can tell me where I failed on my class code.

Thanks all!

**XML**

```
    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorFloatActionButton"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorRipple" />


    <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**JAVA CLASS**

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_web_view_map, container, false);

    mFabButton = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(XXXXXXX.R.id.fabButton);
    mFabButton.setImageResource(XXXXXX.R.drawable.ic_action_new);

    mFabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.webView, new New_Map_Post(), "fragment_screen");
            ft.commit();


        }
    });

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_web_view_map, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/maps/MYMAP");

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return v;


}
```

Comment: your hierarchy is wrong. FloatingActionButton should come after the webview in xml.

Comment: thanks, done but still not working :(

Comment: What's not working? Please post the screenshot of the layout.

Comment: The button it's shown but it have no action when push it.

Comment: try to put a log inside onClick

Comment: I tried and have no signal. I remove the melnykov library and change the floating button to a normal button and It works well. I'll research about floating button and posted if I solved. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You could use the `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` and this should work.